# signalr 400 error for several times when recycling the application pool

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr

When recycling the application pool, SignalR connection is closed and error 400 is raised for about 10 times, and after that the connection is properly established. The application used a static machine key, stored in a file.

I also set PreloadEnabled to true, but it doesn't help.

```
[16:04:51] SignalR: Unclean disconnect from websocket: [no reason given].
Closing the Websocket.
SignalR: webSockets reconnecting.
SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 
WebSocket connection to 'url' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
...
[16:05:07] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'hub'.
[16:05:07] SignalR: webSockets transport starting.
```

The application is ASP.NET Core running on .NET Framework 4.7.1. It uses SignalR 2.

Comment: Recycling the apppool takes time. It could be a few seconds (5 - 30) before the site is available again.

Comment: Shouldn't the preload enable help?

Comment: No, even if it is enabled it still takes time. Preload only means that the pool is activated again without a request.

Comment: So, there is no way to use the new application pool only after it is properly started?

Comment: Yes. But you can turn off automatic apppool recycle or schedule it yourself for a better time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that it was trying to reconnect a closed socket. The solution was to disconnect and connect again.